# tengo problemas al instalar meteor en windows 10.1 last update

Tags: nodejs, windows, cmd, npm

Ejecución en consola:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\jagal>meteor -v
module.js:474
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jagal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\meteo
r\app\meteor\meteor.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:472:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:420:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:137:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:497:3

C:\Users\jagal>
```

este es el error que me marca compañeros?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no parece versar sobre programación

Comment: haz hecho `npm install` ?

Comment: si mi amigo ya ve que ahora meteor tiene su instalador de windows, hace uno el proceso y ya que lo instala abre una venta uno en el cmd y pone un comando de meteor y sale lo que le publique, ej. si pone uno la version de meteor enseguida te despliega lo que le puse arriva.